# Make layout by xml instead programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have this classes

MyTouchEventView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyTouchEventView extends View {

private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();
private Path circlePath = new Path();

public Button btnReset;
public LayoutParams params;

public MyTouchEventView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4f);

    btnReset = new Button(context);
    btnReset.setText("Clear Screen");

    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btnReset.setLayoutParams(params);

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            path.reset();
            postInvalidate();

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);

        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
        circlePath.reset();

        circlePath.addCircle(pointX, pointY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        circlePath.reset();

        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }

    postInvalidate();
    return true;
}
}
```

DrawingBrush.java

```
public class DrawingBrush extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyTouchEventView tv = new MyTouchEventView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
    addContentView(tv.btnReset, tv.params);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

Now I want to convert this

```
    MyTouchEventView tv = new MyTouchEventView(this);
setContentView(tv);
addContentView(tv.btnReset, tv.params);
```

to be as  `setContentView(R.layout.main);`  and put the button and other components that in view in "main.xml" layout

how can I do this? hope anyone got my mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyTouchEventView` should have at least one more constructor. 
This constructor should accept a `AttributeSet` parameter, besides `Context`.

```
public MyTouchEventView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  // perform initialization
}
```

And it will be invoked when the view is declared in XML layout file.

Then, you would declare the view in XML like this:

```
<com.my_package_name.MyTouchEventView
     ....
      />
```

This topic is explained in detail in Android docs. Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: I want to remove MyTouchEventView class and put what in it to the class DrawingBrush

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you just said. But, if you need to use the `MyTouchEventView` in `DrawingBrush`, modify the `MyTouchEventView` class by adding one more constructor, create a new layout XML file, declare the `MyTouchEventView` in that XML file, and then use this XML file in `DrawingBrush`. If you are new to custom views, I highly suggest you pause a bit, and read the docs first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this example http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-custom-views-2/  helped me too